# tr on click change to different tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using Jquery, I have a table and on clicking the table row i want td to change to textbox or dropdown.

After entering the values of textbox i want those values to be updated to that table row on which it was clicked. I have got it partially.

Please help me with this.

This is my html code:

```
<table id="myTable" >
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
 <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#myTable").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").click(function () {
    $(this.parentNode).replaceWith('<tr><td ><textarea></textarea></td><td ><textarea></textarea></td><td ><textarea></textarea></td></tr>').appendTo($(this)).val().select().blur(function () {
        var newText = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newText);
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I don't check if it compile, it is just an idea:

```
$("#myTable").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").click(function () {
    var cell1Text = $(this).find('.cell1').text();
    $(this.parentNode).replaceWith('<tr><td><textarea class="cell1">'+cell1Text+'</textarea></td>...</tr>').appendTo($(this)).val().select().blur(function () {
        var newText = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newText);
    });
})
.blur(function () {
    var cell1Val = $(this).find('.cell1').val();
    $(this.parentNode).replaceWith('<tr class="cell1">'+cell1Val+'<td ></td>...</tr>').appendTo($(this)).val().select().blur(function () {
        var newText = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().text(newText);
    });
});
```